# IntelliJ doesn't save jar in local repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've got a problem, that I've got a maven project and when I am using intelliJ it doesn't update local repository. When I am using netbeans with the same project it saves correctly and I don't know why intelliJ not.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bank</groupId>
<artifactId>facade</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using `mvn install`?

Comment: no, how to use it (never try to do this manually)? just in command line in maven project folder?

Comment: thanks, i have google it and it solved a problem :)

Comment: @karoma you should post an answer, so the question can be closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `mvn install`.

IntelliJ won't automatically do a local install by default.

If you want this, click on `Maven Projects` (usually on the right hand side of the screen, or via the little navigation square in the bottom left), go to `Lifecycle`, right click on `install`, and select `Execute after build`.

[image]